# Return Local Object in a function

Tags: c++

I have done the following code:

```
Xyz CV::Init(Source& node)
{

    if (node == 5)
    {
        Xyz nodeRelay(node.getNodeQ());
        nodeRelay.setInputNode(node);
        return nodeRelay;
    }
}
```

I use it like:

```
Xyz xyz = Init(center);
```

When I try to compile, I get the error:

```
error: use of deleted function
```

I am using C++11 and GCC 4.9.0

XyZ is like this:

```
Xyz::Xyz( uint8_t type ):
BaseNode(),
m_type(type)
{

}
```

The error is in the line:

```
return nodeRelay;
```

If I take that away then it compiles.

Comment: And how does `Xyz`'s declaration look like?

Comment: That's not a class declaration as I've been asking for.

Comment: It sounds like `Xyz` isn't copyable, so you can't return a copy of it. Read the whole of the error message to find out why it isn't. Or post [enough information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to work it out, if you can't figure it out for yourself.

Comment: @user1876942 What do you return if node is not 5?

Answer (score 0):

Returning local objects from function is fine.You are returning Xyz object only when node = 5 ,what if node is not equal to 5. You should return some valid object of Xyz.

Comment: Clearly it's not fine in this case, since it causes a compile error. In general, it's fine if the object has an accessible copy or move constructor.

Comment: When it is not 5 then I thought I would throw an exception.  I did not post all of the code.  Mike Seymour, is right and I am reading about copy constructors.